# Error on line 5873 importing .xls file using PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I'm receiving this error ...**Notice: Undefined offset: 126 in /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/manage/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php on line 5873** when I'm attempting to import a .xls file. Yet it works fine with an xlsx file. If I wave the working .xlsx file as an .xls file it fails?

```
$fPath = "uploads/";

include('./Classes/PHPExcel.php');
include('./Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

// Add file name to file path
$fPath = $fPath . basename($_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
$ext = pathinfo($fPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);    

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'], $fPath)) {
    $output = "";
    if ($ext == "xlsx") {
        $fileType = 'Excel2007';
    } else {
        $fileType = 'Excel5';
    }
    //echo " fileType=$fileType";
    $sheetname = 'IRBIMport';

    // Read the file

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname); 
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fPath);

    $excelOut = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
} else {
    $output = "failed to upload";
}
```

if I comment out this line `$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fPath);` I don't get the error but I'm still haven't got a clue how to resolve?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

File is still uploaded, I can still read the file and rest of my code still works.

So I've just changed my error reporting to `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` ...no more problem :)